# Is a colimit of Banach space topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, limits-colimits

question. 1

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and 
$$
\mathcal{C}(X)=\{ f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \mid f \ \mathrm{is \ continuous}\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{C}_c(X) = \{ f \in \mathcal{C}(X) \mid \mathrm{supp}f  \mathrm{ \ is \ compact} \}
$$
and if $K \subset X$ is compact, 
$$
\mathcal{C}(X,K) = \{ f \in \mathcal{C}(X) \mid \mathrm{supp}f \subset K \}
$$
Define the topology of $\mathcal{C}_c(X)$ as $\varinjlim_K \mathcal{C}(X,K)$.
($\varinjlim_K \mathcal{C}(X,K)$ means the colimt in $\mathbf{Top}$ of Banach spaces $\mathcal{C}_c(K)$)

Then, is $\varinjlim_K \mathcal{C}(X,K)$ topological vector space?
How to prove?

question.2

Especially when $X= \mathbb{R}^n$, is $\varinjlim_K \mathcal{C}(X,K)$ topological vector space?

(I'm sorry my English is broken...I would be glad if you could help me.)

Comment: It depends on the category in weich you take the colimit. In the category TVS of topological vector spaces the answer is trivially yes, but in the category of topological spaces it is probably no.

Comment: Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1432904 is useful?

Comment: As @Jochen comments, probably you want to restrict the category in which you (attempt to) take the colimit. I'd recommend the locally-convex TVS colimit. (There is certainly also a not-necessarily-locally-convex TVS colimit, but it's not the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is "no".

Define $E(X) = \varinjlim_K \mathcal{C}(X,K)$ as the colimit in $\mathbf{Top}$. As a set we have $E(X) = \mathcal{C}_c(X)$, but the topology on $E(X)$ is finer than the norm topology on $\mathcal{C}_c(X)$.

Let $X$ be a discrete space which is clearly locally compact. Then the compact subsets of $X$ are precisely the finite subsets. It is readily seen that $E(X)$ carries the *finite topology*, i.e. $U \subset E(X)$ is open if and only $U \cap V$ is open in $V$ for each finite-dimensional linear subspace $V \subset E(X)$, where $V$ is given the standard Euclidean topology. This is true because each finite dimensional linear subspace is contained in some $\mathcal{C}(X,K)$, the latter being finite dimensional with the Euclidean topology.

It is well-known that that a vector space with the finite topology is never a TVS if its dimension is $\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$. Therefore, if $X$ is discrete with $\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$ elements, then $E(X)$ is no TVS.